# RecyclerView, happy VewHolder pattern

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a question about the view holder pattern. I have a recycler view with the View Holder, and someone from Google said that the best practice is to implement it like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindTo(listItems.get(position), context);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView txtHead;
    private TextView txtDesc;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHead);
        txtDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void bindTo(ListItem item, Context context){
        txtHead.setText(item.getHead());
        txtDesc.setText(item.getDesc());
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(item.getImageUrl())
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
}
```

if you look at the onBind method, it calls a method in the View Holder class. this was implemented with instructions from someone in the RecyclerView team in Google.
My question is why is this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. It basically delegates the responsibility of binding data of the ViewHolder to the ViewHolder itself.

If you would have multiple view types, with multiple view holder classes, then you can use polymorphism to call the same method to bind data, without needing to know the concrete type of the actual view holder.

If you even move ViewHolders as their own classes (not static inner classes), your adapter would be small and pretty.

Comment: The view holder pattern is very important for better performance, but having the binding code in the adapter or in the view holder, is simply a matter of organising your code